# If charged particles have Brownian motion, would this motion be associated with (or produce) heat or electricity?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electricity, thermal-radiation, brownian-motion

If we have charged particles having Brownian motion, would this motion be associated with (or produce) heat or electricity? Would it produce electromagnetic radiation (and if it would produce it, what type of radiation in the electromagnetic spectrum)? Could there be Brownian motion of charged particles in a magnetic field caused by a permanent magnet? And a static electric field?

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the particles having Brownian motion is that they have a non-zero temperature. That is, it is caused by heat. It does not produce heat.

Brownian motion of charged particles does produce electromagnetic radiation. This is called [thermal radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation). When the matter generating this radiation has certain ideal characteristics, the thermal radiation it produces is called [blackbody radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation).

It was the spectrum of blackbody radiation, which does not follow the predictions of classical physics, that led Planck to postulate the quantization of the electromagnetic field, one of key foundations of quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

> Could there be Brownian motion of charged particles in a magnetic field ...?

Yes. That's one of the reasons why it's so hard to handle with plasma in tokamaks. Also particles in  beams in accelerators (e.g. LHC), which are bent by magnetic fields, perform some undesired stochastic motion which must be reduced by [Particle beam cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_beam_cooling).